# Passing variable to partial inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the view.html.erb:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

In each _post.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/block', locals: { blockedcallsign: post.user.callsign } %>
```

In each _block.html.erb:

```
<%= button_to blockrelationships_path(
                params: { 
                  blocker_callsign: @user.callsign, 
                  blocked_callsign: blockedcallsign #'baz'
                },
                remote: true
              ),
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

In _block.html.erb I get the error: `undefined local variable or method 'blockedcallsign'`. When I replace blockedcallsign with a string like 'baz' it works. For some reason blockedcallsign isn't being passed from _post.html.erb to _block.html.erb. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You use the token "blockedcallsign" in many files.  Which is actually throwing the error?

Comment: It's the blockedcallsign in _block.html.erb that causes the error.

Comment: You should edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The latest way is:

```
<%= render 'shared/block', { blockedcallsign: post.callsign } %>
```

Pass as hash.

Comment: what is your rails version please?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're looking for is

`render 'shared/block', locals: {blockedcallsign: post.callsign}` in `_posts.html.erb`

Then, in `_block.html.erb`, you need to call `blockedcallsign` not @blockedcallsign

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code. There was a forgotten second 'render' in view.html.erb causing the problem. Sorry.